# Suppose A is a set of (x, y)', what is the name of the set that consists of all x in A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $A$ be a set of a vector $(\mathbf{x}',\,\mathbf{y}')$. Here $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$ could both be vectors. Is there a particular terminology for the set of all $\mathbf{x}'$ in the set $A$.

Comment: In the case that $A$ is a function i.e. $(x,y),(x,y')\in A\Rightarrow y=y'$ we call it the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides Git Gud's answer, we can also say that it is the *image of $A$ under the projection map $\pi_1$*, where $\pi_1$ is defined by:

$$\pi_1(\mathbf x',\mathbf y') = \mathbf x'$$

This can be denoted symbolically by $\pi_1(A)$ or $\pi_1[A]$; particularly set theorists often prefer the square brackets.

This is because in set theory, one frequently encounters that $A$ is both an *element* and a *subset* of a larger set, rendering the round brackets ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29#Formal_definition) of the [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29) $A$.